# Alter variable directly or use a setter function?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, setter

Which is best practice when setting a variable such as a page title tag from within the page controller?

I have:

```
class About extends Controller {

public function Index()
{
    $this->view->pageTitle = 'test 123' ;
    $this->view->metaDescription = 'Description here' ;
    $this->view->metaKeywords = 'dog, cat, monkey' ;
    $this->view->render('about/about') ;
}
}
```

Or should I use a setter function like:

```
$this->view->setPageTitle('My Title') ;
```

Comment: I didn't really hear what you asked because I was busy looking at your profile pic..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Neither.* View should request data, that it needs, from model layer and decide, based on acquired data, which templates should be used to generate response.

What you currently have is a dumb [template](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html). Since there is no real view, you are not implementing MVC.